# Nikon D500 bracketing wrong exposure preview and histogram

Tags: live-view, bracketing, histogram

I have a problem with my Nikon D500 (firmware 1.13)

I have set up my bracketing to start with underexposed image.

I shoot in manual mode. So I turn live view on and set up exposure for first bracketed image - underexposed one. But my live histogram is moved by +2EV compared to exposure I currently have. It simply shows middle exposure's histogram, not current (underexposed).

In other words - In manual mode I set up exposure time to 1/100 sec but I see live histogram for 1/25 sec. When I take all 3 images and then check their histograms, I see that my first underexposed picture has different (-2EV) histogram than it had in the live view. Middle exposure's histogram is the histogram I saw in live view. Third exposure is overexposed correctly. I am attaching two pictures - first in live view and second in preview of taken image. You can see that histogram (and exposure of course) does not match to what I have seen in live view.

Do you know how to fix this? I would like to see real histogram for my first underexposed exposure. Googling for several hours did not help me.

Thank you for any help!
Martin

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are your images in the opposite order from the way you describe? It looks like the first one is the image preview and the second is the Live View before you took the shot.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much every camera I've ever used that has an exposure bracketing feature always shows the value for the middle exposure. Apparently it is more or less a de facto industry standard.

Most cameras will allow you to select the order the images are taken. You can choose either -, 0, + or 0, -, +. The later is the default setting for most cameras with AEB. But either way, if you are displaying a histogram in Live View, the middle value will be the one displayed.

For most cameras the vertical lines on the histogram are two stops apart.